# Close some apps before suspend automatically?

Tags: 15.04, suspend

When I suspend the system leaving some heavy on RAM apps active, the system crash on the wake from suspend. So right now, I manually close those apps and the system never crashes when awaken.

Is there a way that I tell the system to close those apps (kill can be done safely) before the system goes to suspend?